# php project works on linux server but not on windows

Tags: php, windows, linux, header

So I have two copies of exactly the same project. The configuration of the servers is the same. The script has to write some data to database and then redirect the user to the appropriate page with the `header()` function depending on the data written to the database.

It works fine on the Linux server, though in Windows it tries to redirect first, and then write to the database, which, of course, doesn't work, because there's no data written. If I comment out the `header()` function in the Windows version, it writes to the database, but doesn't do the redirection.

How can two exact scripts work so different?

Edit:

I'm not sure how do I show the code, since there's so much of it and it's so scattered. But basically, it's just a function that sets the `header()` and then the function that writes to db. And when it redirects, it should select the data that was written to the database and display it.

That's a very simplified version of it. Bear in mind, the `header` is set BEFORE the writing to the database. I believe this to be the culprit, but I didn't write the code, and I can't change the architecture of it, since it works perfectly on 2 Linux servers, I just don't understand how. I just need to make it work on the Windows server.

It makes the redirection ok, I mean it sends me to the link that it should send me to, but it doesn't write to the database. But it I comment out the `header()` part, it writes to the database, but doesn't make the redirection.

Comment: You should isolate the problem down to a line or block of code, and post that. Without it, it's impossible to give good info

Comment: Are they running the same web server, at the same version, with the same options?

Comment: can you show us some code? especially the header code that you mentioned that you commented out.

Comment: `it tries to redirect first, and then write to the database`; could you elaborate on that? Does the original script continue while the page has already redirected? Seems unlikely. header() calls are buffered until the first output is generated or the script stops. Perhaps you had output buffering enabled via php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason i've only got it to work on WampServer and with PHP 5.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an if statement like this:

```
if(mysql_query('...') && mysql_affected_rows()){
   header("Location: redirectScript.php");exit();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: But this doesn't address the deeper issue why it works on one server, and doesn't on the other, does it?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) states the following:

> Note:
>
> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as
>   argument to » Location: including the
>   scheme, hostname and absolute path,
>   but some clients accept relative URIs.
>   You can usually use
>   $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
>   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to
>   make an absolute URI from a relative
>   one yourself:

Are you using a relative URL? It's possible that LAMP likes a relative URL more then WAMP does. It is a simple test, so worth a shot.

Comment: It makes the link and the redirection OK, it just doesn't display any data, because there was none written to the database.